# Do I need to create a new Facebook app for each app tab on a page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-page

I recently made an app so i could have an iframe tab on my page. i want to add another tab with an iframe. Can this be done with the same app?

Can i determine which tab a request came from? Its going to be different content under each tab.

I want to keep it the same app so users will not have to grant permissions for a second app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can only define one tab per app. You can configure that tab to display different content for different pages, but you cannot install more than one tab to a page using the same app. You'll have to create multiple apps, but you should be able to point them at the same codebase and determine which app is requesting content to serve the proper tab.

Regarding permissions, I'd work it so that you don't do any authentication from the tab itself but instead you link them to the same installation endpoint.

Comment: Thanks, this is what i needed to know. Setting up new apps wont a problem i just wanted it a little more consolidated.